# How to resolve this error while installing the windows Terminal?

Tags: windows, windows-terminal

I have tried these possible method to install Windows Terminal as mentioned in the microsoft terminal github release pages- https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

I am on windows 10 version 21H1(OS Build 19043.1165).
On installing from the microsoft store,I get the error code - 0x80070241

I have also tried downloading the .msixbundle and installing from the app installer but I get this error-

App installation failed with error message: Failed to initialize a MRT resource manager for the inbox application: Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_1.10.1933.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe and file path: resources.pri . (0x80070241).

On installing via powershell I get this-

Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package could not be registered.
Failed to initialize a MRT resource manager for the inbox application:
Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_1.10.1933.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe and file path: resources.pri .
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 147c0615-9472-0004-9f03-7f147294d701 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 147c0615-9472-0004-9f03-7f147294d701
At line:1 char:1

- Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_1.10.1933.0_8wekyb3d ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\...bbwe.msixbundle:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
  ```

I dont know what is MRT resource manager.I dont understand this error.How to install the terminal?

Comment: Are you installing as administrator or admin user

Comment: I am installing as administrator.

Comment: I mean the user called administrator or if you are running as an admin user, from an elevated prompt.

Comment: MRT is explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/using-mrt-for-converted-desktop-apps-and-games

Comment: No I think I am running as an admin user.

Comment: But if I run powershell as administrator how to access the downloads file stored in downloads folder of the admin user.

Comment: As administrator, you can access all files.  Just cd to it.

Comment: When I run the powershell as administrator and cd into c:/users/<my_user_name>/Downloads and run the command  -Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_1.10.1933.0_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundl,it says Add-AppxPackage : Cannot find path....
because it doesnot exist.But the Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_1.10.1933.0_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle file is there in the downloads folder.

Comment: Try putting a .\ in front of the package name

Comment: Its not working. Do you know anything about the app installer error message mentioned in the question?

Comment: That error message is a generic catchall for a whole raft of things that can go wrong.  They are listed in https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-code-0x80070241/109ff795-10c3-415b-8b50-369b7cb65558.  When I was getting an error with Windows Terminal Install, I found that just running as Administrator just worked but that obviously doesn't work for you.  You could try the full path name of the package.  See if that works.